# How/where to enable CORS(cross origin resource sharing)?

Tags: javascript, cors, cross-domain

I am not able to access cross domain resources from my *javascript* file using *XMLHttpRequest()*. 
I understand that there are a few similar questions, I went through some of them but I have a bit of confusion regarding some of the details. 
I will mention my exact Setup and my specific doubts.

Setup:

I have my HTML and JS files on an apache server running on a ubuntu machine present in my local LAN network . The application is bascially hls plugin for video.js.
From my windows PC in the same local LAN, I open the index.html file for the hls player. As long as I select video content which is present on the linux machine, it works fine as expected, but on giving it an external content( E.g. http://devimages.apple.com/iphone/samples/bipbop/bipbopall.m3u8), it fails and gives the error:

*XMLHttpRequest cannot load http://devimages.apple.com/iphone/samples/bipbop/bipbopall.m3u8. No 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header is present on the requested resource. Origin 'http://172.20.33.49' is therefore not allowed access.*

(Here 172.20.33.49 is the IP of the linux machine)

So my queries are:

1. On which server should the *Access-Control-Allow-Origin* header be set to appropriate value(lets say '*' for simplicity) for this to work: on my local linux server or the server hosting the external content or both?
2. Is there any setting/configuration/code change which I need to do in my browser/javascript or HTML code for this to work?
3. As a general query, is there anything the client can/should do for CORS to work or is it purely a server requirement/configuration?
4. Is the '*Access-Control-Allow-Origin*' mandatory in HTTP responses? If not then what does its absence mean - Does it mean only resources from same domain can be accessed or does it mean all domains are accessible(equivalent to *) ? Is there any way a client can force a server to add this header?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> On which server should the Access-Control-Allow-Origin header be set

The server hosting the content you want to read with XHR. The error message does spell this out, it tells you the URL to a resource that you are requesting and then says that the header is not present on that resource.

> Is there any setting/configuration/code change which I need to do in my browser/javascript or HTML code for this to work?

No. The browser handles CORS transparently.

> As a general query, is there anything the client can/should do for CORS to work or is it purely a server requirement/configuration?

The client has to support CORS. All modern browsers do.

> Is the 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' mandatory in HTTP responses?

No

> If not then what does its absence mean - Does it mean only resources from same domain can be accessed or does it mean all domains are accessible(equivalent to *) ?

If a server doesn't specify Access-Control-Allow-Origin then it doesn't grant permission to any other origin to read its data.

> Is there any way a client can force a server to add this header?

No (although a browser extension can intercept the response and add the header, this can be useful for testing purposes).

Comment: Thanks for the detailed response.
So if I understand correctly, in this specific case, there is no way for me to play the external content (apart from installing a browser plugin which will intercept and modify the response), since I do not have control on the external server?
On a slightly different note, is this a common/typical behavior for most servers to not allow access from other domains. I mean this would seem to severely limit access for any javascript code?

Comment: Yes, this is normal. Severely limited access for JavaScript is a good thing. You wouldn't want any website you visited to be able to make requests to Gmail as you and read your email? Or your online banking? Cross origin requests require the supplier of the data to actively say that it is safe and desirable.